# Extract frames from specific times from video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am using video js in my react application. I am streaming video from a video url and not from local machine. I have a video url which I give to my player. I want to capture/Extract some frames from the video

**Problem:** Let's say I have time-in and time-out give as 20 sec and 30 sec respectively. I want to randomly extract 4 frames between 20 to 30 sec. I don't want it to get extracted when video reaches 20 sec by playing it. I want to extract the frames as soon as the page gets loaded.

Here is what I have tried

```
async componentDidMount() {

        this.init()
        timeline_width = document.getElementById("timeline").offsetWidth

        let frames = await this.extractFramesFromVideo(this.props.video_reducer.selected_video_file);
    }

async extractFramesFromVideo(videoUrl, fps=25) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {

            // fully download it first (no buffering):
            let videoBlob = await fetch(videoUrl).then(r => r.blob());
            let videoObjectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
            let video = document.createElement("video");

            let seekResolve;
            video.addEventListener('seeked', async function() {
                if(seekResolve) seekResolve();
            });

            video.addEventListener('loadeddata', async function() {
                let canvas = document.getElementById('prevImgCanvas');
                let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                let [w, h] = [video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight]
                canvas.width =  w;
                canvas.height = h;

                let frames = [];
                let interval = 1 / fps;
                let currentTime = 0;
                let duration = video.duration;

                while(currentTime < duration) {
                    video.currentTime = currentTime;
                    await new Promise(r => seekResolve=r);

                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
                    let base64ImageData = canvas.toDataURL();
                    frames.push(base64ImageData);

                    currentTime += interval;
                }
                resolve(frames);
            });

            // set video src *after* listening to events in case it loads so fast
            // that the events occur before we were listening.
            video.src = videoObjectUrl;

        });
    }
```

But this extracts all the frames of the video. I just want specific frames.

Can someone please suggest a solution to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have to get still image from the video below,

```
<video id="video" controls="controls">
      <source src=".mp4" />
</video> 
<button id="capture">Capture</button> 
<div id="output"></div>
```

Use the following function to get the image from the video before it loads:

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var video, $output;
var scale = 0.25;

var initialize = function() {
    $output = $("#output");
    video = $("#video").get(0);
    $("#capture").click(captureImage);                
};

var captureImage = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth * scale;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight * scale;
    canvas.getContext('2d')
          .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    $output.prepend(img);
};

$(initialize);    
}());
```

Thanks to Chris Brandsma, i have used this on wordpress as custom code and made some changes according to my work, so you need to add some code to get random time based images.
You can find this code on: [Tutorial Code](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/04/capturing-html-5-video-to-an-image.aspx)

Comment: But I don't want all the frames of the video. I just want specific frames